# Extracting one file from archive: 7-zip requires decompressing entire archive?

Tags: windows, performance, compression, 7-zip, rar

I've noticed that when browsing an archive containing multiple files with 7-zip 9.20 Windows GUI, extracting one file for previewing takes significantly longer with .7z than .rar archives. With .7zips it also cycles through the filenames in the archive. To me it looks like decompressing the entire archive and keeping just one file.

Is there a setting in 7-zip (current or beta/alpha versions) that allows RAR-like behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the `Solid Block size` option to `Non-solid`. RAR supports [solid compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_compression) too, but perhaps it's not enabled by default.

Comment: Wow, such an useful feature and not enabled by default on 7-zip? It doesn't even increase the file size noticeably...